# send post data from php to webadress without redirecting

Tags: php, asp.net, redirect, post

I have a PHP page at a site `www.aaa.com` and on that page when I click the send button it should send textbox data as post data to a ASPX webpage at `www.bbb.com`.

I need the relevant ASPX code for retrieving post data into textbox and submitting automatically.

How do i do that?

Comment: Can you change the html/javascript of your html page?

Comment: When the data gets sent to aspx page, the aspx page should capture data from post header and get it into text box and automatically the form should get submitted. Any idea on how to do that? I am a total beginner. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Which of the existing questions do not cover your issue? Also it's highly likely that it is not possible what you ask for, so not constructive.

Answer (score 3):

If this is your website - try GET.
If not, you can CURL

Comment: Yes both are my websites. In the aspx page, how do i retrieve values from POST Header and display in a textbox?

Comment: @rishijasapara: You do that by programming ASPX. Is that your issue?

Comment: @hakre: Yes i need the relevant aspx code for retrieving post data into textbox and submitting automatically

Comment: @rishijasapara: I put that into your question. Maybe someone of the ASPX folks can guide you about that, but it sounds like very basic material and it is normally expected that users do know a little about programming before asking. You should also add your code what you have tried so far to make your question more clear - if you really want to get some useful answers.

Comment: I agree I should know that. But I am still learning, so somewhere or the other i am bound to stuck and i expect my seniors to guide me through so that i can learn and share my knowledge too later on. Thank you @hakre :)

Comment: Then contact your senior trainers, we're not here for training but answering programming questions. Start to code it and if you run into a problem, ask about it on site.

Comment: @hakre: I have coded the site. Its not that am asking for help without trying. I couldnt find a solution hence I posted for help here. Sorry for hurting your sentiments.

Comment: Well naturally I mean the code for your solution that does not work yet. Just wrap something up your own of what you want, and if there is  a single part you don't know how to do that (e.g. how is post represented in ASPX), search for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you can afford to rely on a client side solution, you can use `jQuery` [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in order to achieve that. Quoting the jQuery API page, the $.ajax() function:

> Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

Then you can use a similar code as below to send your data as `POST` and then retrieve any responses the server provides (EDITED to cross-site functionality):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourfolder/bbb.com?myparameter=myargument',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonp: false, //or else the first json element will be a ?
    data: $("#my-form-text-area").val(), //the data sent to the server
    success: function(receivedData) {
        alert("This is the data received from the server: " + receivedData.myJsonField);
  }
```

});

`$.ajax` requests are async by default which means the processing will occur in your server and the `success` function will only display data when it gets a response.

Comment: Would need to mention JSONP, no?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I implemented this on my php page :)

Comment: I edited the answer for a cross-site solution. Thank you @ficuscr for reminding me that the OP wanted a cross-site solution